# How to enable ART accelerator STM32F407VGT6

Tags: arm

I keep reading about the ART accelerator on the STM32F407VGT6 and zero wait states at 168MHz and it is mentioned briefly in the data sheet but I can't find anywhere how to enable it.
There is a prefetch option in the FLASH_ACR register but enabling it causes my board to stop 
working. Not sure if this is the same thing. Is ART even something that needs to be enabled or is it enabled by default? I notice in the errata for this chip that the ART was not working in A version but has been "fixed" in the current Z rev.

Thanks

Comment: I am as confused about whether or not it is enabled by default either.  I have some examples for the stm32f4 discovery http://github.com/dwelch67/stm32f4d with it cranked up to 168Mhz and the caches and prefetch and such on.  If you change the FLASH_ACR make sure you have the right number of wait states depending on your processor speed or it will crash/hang...For example 5 wait states for 3.3Volts 168Hz...Or maybe if you are already running then do a read-modify-write to turn on the icache and prefetch.

Comment: I have it set for 5 wait states at 168mhz like it says to do and still with prefetch it hangs. What is very mysterious is it quotes performance figures for both enabled and disabled in the data sheet. Sounds like a question for STM tech support

Answer (score 0):

This [link](http://www.st.com/internet/com/TECHNICAL_RESOURCES/TECHNICAL_LITERATURE/APPLICATION_NOTE/DM00033348.pdf) has the method of configuring the ART for stm32F2 devices. The same registers are found in the STM32f4 discovery series. Check for the word ART configuration in the pdf.  I'm having the same problem and this is the best answer I could find...

Comment: Yeah I still find that confusing. I think ART is misleading as it is only 0 wait states at certain clock speeds and it needs 5 wait states if running at 168MHz

Answer (score 0):

I read in that document: STMicroelectronics: AN3430 - Application Note of How to achieve the lowest current consumption with STM32F2xx

On page 17 (3.1.1) they say that enabling the buffer prefetch will consume additional 20mA (for 128-bit-line fetching).
Maybe at 168 MHz you power supply gets unstable??
Maybe you can try it with lower clock speed (120MHz), where the cpu is very power efficient.